# Why is my RegexExp not working properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

i have an array of strings with that contain a number of different characters. i am looping through the array and using the .replace(RegExp,Replacement) method, But i cant seem to get it to work properly.The expression that i am using is "/[^\w\d]". I am trying to remove anything that is not a letter or number including Spaces and replace it with an "_"(to make it nice for a file name). Ive tested the regex above and it is supposed to be correct. But i am getting weird and unwanted results.The following code will reproduce my problem.

```
var StringArray = ["ABCdef123®","ABCdef/123®","ABCde f123®","ABCde/f123®","AB Cde\\f123®"];
const myRegex = new RegExp("/[^\w\d]");
var NewString;
var counter = 0;

StringArray.forEach(function(item){
 NewString = item.replace(myRegex,"_");
 console.log("Old String: " + item);
 console.log("New String: "+ NewString);
 counter++;
})
```

The Output will look like this

```
Old String: ABCdef123®
New String: ABCdef123®

Old String: ABCdef/123®
New String: ABCdef_23®

Old String: ABCde f123®
New String: ABCde f123®

Old String: AB Cde/f123®
New String: AB Cde_123®

Old String: AB Cde\f123®
New String: AB Cde\f123®
```

it will not find backslashes or the "®" symbol. and when it does find something it is also removing the following character. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You want just `const myRegex = /[^\w\d]/;`

Comment: This actually solved my issue, But i also needed to add the global match 
    (/[^\w\d]/g) at the end for it to work properly.i haven't tried the other answers yet but each has its own variation is any one better than the other?

Comment: The btmorex answer is correct then: `/\W/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const myRegex = /\W/g;
```

works. You want the g to replace all occurrences. Your new Regexp syntax is wrong. It shouldn't include the slash.

Comment: i used this in the end. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `/\W/` which means: not a letter, digit or `_`:

```js
var StringArray = ["ABCdef123®","ABCdef/123®","ABCde f123®","ABCde/f123®","AB Cde\\f123®"];
const myRegex = new RegExp(/\W/, 'g');
var NewString;
var counter = 0;

StringArray.forEach(function(item){
 NewString = item.replace(myRegex,"_");
 console.log("Old String: " + item);
 console.log("New String: "+ NewString);
 counter++;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a regex for non-letter-and-non-digits, it's `\W`.

```
const myRegex = /\W/g;
```

It's supposed to do the trick :)